# C++ Boost::variant error using boost::get on my user defined type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-variant

I'm trying to learn how to use Boost::variant by using the Boost basic usage online tutorial at (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html). To get the hang of it, I tried taking some of the code from the tutorial(below)...

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

void times_two(boost::variant<int, std::string, std::complex<double> > & v) {
    if (int* pi = boost::get<int>(&v))
        *pi *= 2;
    else if (std::string* pstr = boost::get<std::string>(&v))
        *pstr += *pstr;
    //No check for complex - will silently return when variant is complex (BAD).
}

int main() {
    boost::variant<int, std::string, std::complex<double> > v;
    v = "hello";
    std::string& str = boost::get<std::string>(v);
    str += " world! ";
//the std::string contained by v now is equal to "hello world! ". Again, we can demonstrate this by streaming v to standard output:
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    times_two(v);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::complex<double> a(5.0, 6.0);
    v = a;
    times_two(v);
    return 0;
}
```

^ It compiles fine and returns "hello world! 
hello world! hello world!" as expected, taking on the complex type before returning.

Then I tried modifying it...

But as soon as I added my own struct, "structy" into the variant example program, like so:

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

struct structy {
    int a;
};

void times_two(
        boost::variant<int, std::string, std::complex<double>, structy> & v) {
    if (int* pi = boost::get<int>(&v))
        *pi *= 2;
    else if (std::string* pstr = boost::get<std::string>(&v))
        *pstr += *pstr;
    //No check for complex or structy - should silently returns.
}

int main() {

    boost::variant<int, std::string, std::complex<double>, structy> v;
    v = "hello";
    std::string& str = boost::get<std::string>(v);
    str += " world! ";
//As desired, the std::string contained by v now is equal to "hello world! ". Again, we can demonstrate this by streaming v to standard output:
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    times_two(v);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::complex<double> a(5.0, 6.0);
    v = a;
    times_two(v);
    return 0;
}
```

I got a massive error message upon compilation with g++4.7 . I don't understand what it says, but I will include it for reference.

Why I can't get it to work with the data types that I define? Note that I get this same humongous error message when I try to use boost::static_visitor with my own user defined classes as well.

The big error message is below:

```
johnmichaelreed@Ubuntu1204LTS:~/Downloads/boost_1_54_0$ g++ ~/temp.cpp -o temp 
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2416:0,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
             from /home/johnmichaelreed/temp.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::detail::variant::printer<OStream>::operator()(const T&) const [with T = structy, OStream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1017:32:   instantiated from ‘boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::result_type boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::internal_visit(T&, int) [with T = const structy, Visitor = boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> >, boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::result_type = void]’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:130:9:   instantiated from ‘typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl(int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, T*, mpl_::true_) [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> > >, VoidPtrCV = const void*, T = structy, typename Visitor::result_type = void, mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:173:9:   instantiated from ‘typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke(int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, T*, NoBackupFlag, int) [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> > >, VoidPtrCV = const void*, T = structy, NoBackupFlag = boost::variant<int, std::basic_string<char>, std::complex<double>, structy>::has_fallback_type_, typename Visitor::result_type = void]’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:260:1:   instantiated from ‘typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl(int, int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, mpl_::false_, NoBackupFlag, Which*, step0*) [with Which = mpl_::int_<0>, step0 = boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_step<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<4l>, int, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<3l>, std::basic_string<char>, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<2l>, std::complex<double>, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<1l>, structy, boost::mpl::l_end> > > > >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_end> >, Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> > >, VoidPtrCV = const void*, NoBackupFlag = boost::variant<int, std::basic_string<char>, std::complex<double>, structy>::has_fallback_type_, typename Visitor::result_type = void, mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2326:13:   instantiated from ‘static typename Visitor::result_type boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::internal_apply_visitor_impl(int, int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV) [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> > >, VoidPtrCV = const void*, T0_ = int, T1 = std::basic_string<char>, T2 = std::complex<double>, T3 = structy, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_, typename Visitor::result_type = void]’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2348:13:   instantiated from ‘typename Visitor::result_type boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::internal_apply_visitor(Visitor&) const [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> > >, T0_ = int, T1 = std::basic_string<char>, T2 = std::complex<double>, T3 = structy, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_, typename Visitor::result_type = void]’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2370:52:   instantiated from ‘typename Visitor::result_type boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::apply_visitor(Visitor&) const [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> >, T0_ = int, T1 = std::basic_string<char>, T2 = std::complex<double>, T3 = structy, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_, typename Visitor::result_type = void]’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp:88:5:   instantiated from ‘std::basic_ostream<E, T>& boost::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<E, T>&, const boost::variant<U0, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U11, U12, U13, U14, U15, U16, U17, U18, U19>&) [with E = char, T = std::char_traits<char>, U0 = int, U1 = std::basic_string<char>, U2 = std::complex<double>, U3 = structy, U4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]’
/home/johnmichaelreed/temp.cpp:25:16:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp:64:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘((const boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> >*)this)->boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char> >::out_ << operand’
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp:64:9: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:110:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:110:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&) {aka std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:119:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:119:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:129:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:129:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:167:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:167:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘long int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:171:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:171:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:175:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:175:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘bool’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:93:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:93:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘short int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:182:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:182:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘short unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:107:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:107:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:193:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:193:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:202:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:202:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘long long int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:206:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:206:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘long long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:211:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:211:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘double’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:215:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:215:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘float’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:223:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:223:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘long double’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:227:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:227:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘const void*’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:121:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:121:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const structy’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}’
/usr/local/include/boost/blank.hpp:93:46: note: template<class E, class T> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& boost::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const boost::blank&)
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp:79:46: note: template<class E, class T, class U0, class U1, class U2, class U3, class U4, class U5, class U6, class U7, class U8, class U9, class U10, class U11, class U12, class U13, class U14, class U15, class U16, class U17, class U18, class U19> std::basic_ostream<E, T>& boost::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<E, T>&, const boost::variant<U0, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U11, U12, U13, U14, U15, U16, U17, U18, U19>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:521:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:528:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:523:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:510:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:323:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:493:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:473:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:468:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:462:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:456:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:451:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
johnmichaelreed@Ubuntu1204LTS:~/Downloads/boost_1_54_0$
```

What does this error mean? Why did my modification break the code?

Comment: It could be your type not overloading `operator<<`.

Comment: I never assign something of user defined type "structy" to my variant, and I certainly didn't try to use the stream operator on it or try to print it out, so I didn't think that overloading the stream operator for structy was necessary for it to compile.

Comment: I suspect it's because you output the variant. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc68b2b14287ecd3

Comment: Please explain how that works. So you have to define all the functions and operators that are invoked on the variant even if the variant in that particular type (structy) never explicitly uses them (ostream)? It would be good if you made it an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: I have no idea. I've never used one and have barely read into that particular library.

Comment: Aww shoot. I also wanted to know the difference between "class my_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<int>" and "class my_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>". Because on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html, it gives me the first version and on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html is gives me the second, but it doesn't explain them in depth. In both  tutorial, it appears that the angle brackets match the return type, but I don't know why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c

Comment: What's the connection between public, private, and protected inheritance and static_visitor?

Comment: Honestly, I'm having so much trouble learning this library that I'm seriously considering giving each struct in my program an integer data member called "type" and then giving each type an enum value that corresponds with it. Then I would go "if (struct.type == 1) {//do something} else if (struct.type == 2) {//do something else}"

Answer (score 2):

@chris is correct in his guess, it is because of missing operator <<.

These errors are "by design" of Boost.Variant, they prevent you from forgetting to do something you have to do to define correct `variant`.

Indeed, when you use `boost::variant<T1,T2,T3> v` with some function or operator, you expect that you will have some processing for the case the variable v is of type T1, and some other processing for the case it is of type T2 and even some handling for the case when v is actually of type T3.

When you read the Variant tutorial further, you will find that the recommended implementation of the function `times_two` goes through a variant visitor. Unlike your (initial) implementation, the latter would also issue an error if a programmer forgets to implement the visiting function (aka operator()) for some of the types T1,T2,T3.

Now, such visitor implementation is already put in place (by Boost) for standard C++ features like `operator <<(variant<...>,ostream&)`. Since your `struct structy` does not allow operator <<, compiler issues an error.

Unfortunate effect is that the error is somewhat cryptic. It is often the case when errors are caused by operator<< because C++ has so many overloads for it, and compiler tries and mentions all of them.